# Return in a method with multiple method inside

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have a method with multiple method that return a Boolean value and i want to return the first method if any of the method return false.

```
    public Boolean methodA(){
    methodB();
    methodC();
    methodD();
    }
```

Is there any way to return and not continue evaluating the rest if any of the methodB,C,D return false without checking one for one?

Comment: you can use logical and (`&&`) like this `return methodB() && methodC() && methoD();`

Comment: Do you mean that, for example, if methodB returns true, then call methodC, and if methodC returns false then return false from methodA without calling methodD?

Answer (score 5):

Use boolean operators and rely on [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
public boolean methodA(){
    return methodB() && methodC() && methodD();
}
```

Consecutive methods will not be executed after one method returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps to resolve your question, thanks

```
public Boolean methodA(){
if(!methodB()) return false;
if(!methodC()) return false;
if(!methodD()) return false;
return true;
}
```